# jquery validator dropdown menu validation keeps adding a field required post after selection and submit

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have created a form and survey in HTML in which the user will fill out the info and select the drop down menu items as answers to questions.

The problem is that after not selecting a required drop down menu the user is prompted that the field is required. If they now select that drop down and hit submit, another required post is printed and the form does not send to the thank you page. If you keep hitting the submit it just keeps posting required field one after another. Below is a link to the form on my server.

**LINK TO FORM:**
http://amckeedesignportfolio.com/eLearningModule/newForm.php

**HERE IS MY HTML**

```
<h3>
  1. How often do you have a patient who resists oral care? 
  <span style="padding-left:25px;"></span>
</h3>
<br/>
<select name="question1" class="surveySelection1_class">
  <option value=""selected="selected">--select--</option>
  <option value="Never">Never</option>
  <option value="Rarely">Rarely</option>
  <option value="Sometimes">Sometimes</option>
  <option value="Always">Always</option>
</select>

<h3>
  2. How often do you have a patient bite on oral swabs with oral care? 
  <span style="padding-left:25px;"></span>
</h3>
<select name="question2" class="surveySelection2_class">
  <option value=""selected="selected">--select--</option>
  <option value="Never">Never</option>
  <option value="Rarely">Rarely</option>
  <option value="Sometimes">Sometimes</option>
  <option value="Always">Always</option>
</select>
```

**HERE IS THE JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  // validate signup form on keyup and submit
  $("#contactForm").validate({
    rules: {
      fName: "required",
      lName: "required",
      telephone: "required",
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      telephone: {
        required: true,
        phoneUS: true
      },
      position      : "required",
      hospital      : "required",
      hospitalCity  : "required",
      hospitalState : "required",
      floor         : "required",
      experience    : "required",
      question1     : "required",
      question2     : "required",
      question3     : "required",
      question4     : "required",
      question5     : "required",
      question6     : "required",
      question7     : "required",
      question8     : "required",
      question9     : "required",
      question10    : "required",
      question11    : "required",
    },

    messages: {
      fName        : "Please enter your firstname.",
      lName        : "Please enter your lastname.",
      telephone    : "Please enter a valid telephone number.",
      email        : "Please specify a valid email address.",
      position     : "Please enter your current position.",
      hospitalCity : "Please enter your current hospital.",
      floor        : "Please enter the current floor or area you work.",
    }
  });

  /* state validation*/
  $validator.addMethod(
    "state_class",
    function(value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || ( value.indexOf("") == -1);
    },
    "Please select a state."); 

  /* experience validation*/
  $validator.addMethod(
    "selection_class",
    function(value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || ( value.indexOf("") == -1);
    },
    "Please share your experience with us."); 

  /* question1 validation*/
  $validator.addMethod(
    "surveySelection1_class",
    function(value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || ( value.indexOf("") == -1);
    },
    "Please choose an answer."); 

  /* question2 validation*/
  $validator.addMethod(
    "surveySelection2_class",
    function(value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || ( value.indexOf("") == -1);
    },
    "Please choose an answer.");

  /* question3 validation*/
  $validator.addMethod(
    "surveySelection3_class",
    function(value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || ( value.indexOf("") == -1);
    },
    "Please choose an answer.");

  /* question4 validation*/
  $validator.addMethod(
    "surveySelection4_class",
    function(value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || ( value.indexOf("") == -1);
    },
    "Please choose an answer.");

  /* question5 validation*/
  $validator.addMethod(
    "surveySelection5_class",
    function(value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || ( value.indexOf("") == -1);
    },
    "Please choose an answer.");

  /* question6 validation*/
  $validator.addMethod(
    "surveySelection6_class",
    function(value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || ( value.indexOf("") == -1);
    },
    "Please choose an answer.");

  /* question7 validation*/
  $validator.addMethod(
    "surveySelection7_class",
    function(value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || ( value.indexOf("") == -1);
    },
    "Please choose an answer.");

  /* question8 validation*/
  $validator.addMethod(
    "surveySelection8_class",
    function(value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || ( value.indexOf("") == -1);
    },
    "Please choose an answer.");

  /* question9 validation*/
  $validator.addMethod(
    "surveySelection9_class",
    function(value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || ( value.indexOf("") == -1);
    },
    "Please choose an answer.");

  /* question10 validation*/
  $validator.addMethod(
    "surveySelection10_class",
    function(value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || ( value.indexOf("") == -1);
    },
    "Please choose an answer.");

  /* question11 validation*/
  $validator.addMethod(
    "surveySelection11_class",
    function(value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || ( value.indexOf("") == -1);
    },
    "Please choose an answer.");
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you've write to much code to validate your form...
Validating select with jquery-validation plugin is very simple.
You have to make sure that there is an option with an empty value.
And then you just add the "required" class to the select.

```
<select id="mySelect" class="required">
  <option value="">--select--</option>
  <option value="value1">option 1</option>
  <option value="value2">option 2</option>
  <option value="value3">option 3</option>
</select>
```

See the exemple : [select validation example](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/multipart/)

Try to do your validation like this, it should solve your problem.

Comment: so i changed all the classes to required and the first one being the state works but rest just do the same thing. do you have to include a $valdiator.addMethod for every drop down or is it ok to have one with all of the classes being set to required. It is still not working.